# SortedSet ValueError not in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a `SortedSet` from the [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library. The set contains `Match` objects which define a `start` attribute which is used to sort:

```
class Match:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.start < other.start
```

Matches are constantly added (`SortedSet.add`) and discarded (`SortedSet.discard`) from the set.

Matches may have the same start. Matches may see their start changed while existing in the set.

Everything seems to work without any issues until I get the following error when trying to discard a match `sortedset.discard(match)`:

```
ValueError: <Match: X vs Y> not in list
```

The `match` is present in the set, as `match in sortedset` returns `True`. Not that it should matter since `discard` removes quietly.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and I have been trying to figure out a solution for a couple of days, no success yet. I would provide more information if I had any clue of what may be wrong, but I am just clueless. Please ask any information you need and I will deliver.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: @Graipher read my last paragraph: "I would provide more information if I had any clue of what may be wrong, but I am just clueless." I have no idea why this is happenening; it works for a while, then it stops working. Why? No idea.

Comment: Then start from scratch, and try to construct a minimal example that shows this problem (add just one element and remove it again for example). Without being able to reproduce the problem it is almost impossible for us to help you (unless one has encountered this problem before and recognizes it solely from your description, which is unlikely).

Comment: @Graipher I am not able to reproduce an example that shows this problem. I have tried. The problem never happens. It only happens in my project, who knows why.

Comment: You could try to see if `match in sortedset._list`, which is the underlying list in which the order is stored (and which raises the `ValueError` when `self._list.remove(value)` is being called inside of [`SortedSet.remove`](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-sortedcontainers/blob/master/sortedcontainers/sortedset.py)). It might be that some of the changing of the match does not get properly propagated to that internal list.

Comment: Note that `SortedSet.discard` calls internally `SortedList.remove`, instead of `SortedSet.discard` (which would ignore the case that the value is not included in the internal list). It also does not check that the value is in the the internal list before calling it. This might be a bug in `SortedSet`.

Comment: @Graipher That must be it then, because `match in sortedset._list` returns `False`. I am going to have to ditch the library, a pity, because it has pretty handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Matches may have the same start. Matches may see their start changed while existing in the set.

This violates the constraints that containers use to track their elements.

- You can't change the sort order of an element while it is in a container. The container has no way of knowing that the sort order has changed.
- Objects must be different.

If you read the documentation for `sortedset`, it clearly states:

> The hash and total ordering of values must not change while they are stored in the sorted set.

- There doesn't even exist a total ordering for your elements, because there exist `x != y` where it is neither true that `x < y` or `x > y`.
- You haven't mentioned `__hash__` at all.

I am not sure how you would expect to solve these problems, since I am not familiar with your code, and solving them may require some redesign work. However, these problems are what is causing the unexpected behavior in your program.

Comment: I totally missed that part in the documentation, I thought objects could be mutable. I am not sure what you mean with your last two points. And how do you suggest I should go about modifying my data structure choice to meet my needs?

Comment: Objects can be mutable. You just can't change their position while they are in the set. Imagine that I give you a collection of books and you put them on your shelf in alphabetical order. Then, during the night, I sneak into your room and change the titles of the books so they're not in alphabetical order any more. That's what you're doing.

Comment: Doesn't being able to change their `start` means they're mutable? Maybe I'm getting the concept wrong. In any case, I'm still missing that part of your answer I mentioned.

Comment: You can change `start` but (1) you cannot change the total order of the objects in the collection and (2) you cannot change the hash of any object in the collection. In general, the easiest way to do this is to simply not change the object keys while they are in collections, and the easiest way to do that is to make the object keys immutable. You are free to make things hard for yourself, of course. But it is probably easier to redesign your system so you don't need to change object keys for objects in collections.

Comment: @DeitrichEpp well the keys don't change. The keys are `Match` objects. It's `match.start` what changes. How am I changing the order of the objects?

Comment: You are using `match.start` as the key for sorting.

Comment: Alright I get it now. So what would you suggest I do to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: Stop changing `start` while objects are in the set. Define `__hash__`. Define a total order on your elements, which will typically require including something else in the key besides `start`.

Comment: I can't just stop changing `start`, it's a thing that's constatly happening in my program. And `Match` is hashable already.

Comment: @dabadaba: If you can't stop changing `start` then you can't put a `Match` in a `SortedSet`. Solution: don't put `Match` in a `SortedSet`.